# How do you get the 4 corners of a rectangle for any line that has a start coord and end coord in Java

Tags: java, geometry, trigonometry

I would like to know how to calculate the four corners of a rectangle.
I have various straight lines at different orientations. I would like
to use the start and end coordinates of each of these lines to determine a rectangle i.e using the addition or subtraction of diffx, diffy to the start and end points of the line dependent on the bearing of the line in whole circle quadrant. I am trying to do this in java.

My end goal is the have a rectangle (sleeve) to contain the line. The line would
appear as a centre-line to the rectangle or (rectangle buffer of the line).
Grateful for any help

Please see the slide on Assignment 2 on this link. It is a link to someone elses page and shows the image of what I am trying to do
http://blog.wijono.org/2015/07/simple-2d-tesselation-and-twist-with.html
[link](http://blog.wijono.org/2015/07/simple-2d-tesselation-and-twist-with.html)
link

Comment: Is the line the diagonal of a rectangle, or one of its axis?  If it is an axis, are you interested in a specific width, or is that being passed as a parameter?  Diagonals is easy, axis will take a little vector math.

Comment: A picture would come in handy.

Comment: Hi There, unfortunately don't have a scanner to scan a picture. The lines I have need to bisect the height of the rectangle on either end of rectangle. There are no diagonals involved. Each of the lines have different orientations

Comment: I have a height and width that I give for the rectangle. From these was looking to take 1/2 height and use with trig to get diffx and diffx to add or subtract from start and end points to get rectangle coords

Comment: Then my answer is probably the one you want.

Comment: Your description is still very unclear.  If you could add a picture in the question, hand drawn or found somewhere, it would instantly simplify all explanation.  Currently it sounds like you're asking for two different things, a line that defines a diagonal of a rectangle that has horizontal and vertical edges, or a line with a buffer around it going straight outwards and forming a rectangle off of that.

Comment: Draco18s  Thanks for this. I am not sure if your Vec2 is a java api class or your own class?

Comment: Its an arbitrary means of storing two floating point numbers.  You can use a `float[2]` or a custom class or the `Point` class, whatever is familiar to you.  I primarily work with Unity (which has `Vector2` and `Vector3` objects) or Minecraft (which uses a custom `Vec3` class).  Same with the returned `Rect` object.  It's just a `float[4][2]`

Answer (score 1):

Using points `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)` for the start and end of the line.

Top left `( Math.min(x1, x2), Math.min(y1, y2) )`

Top right: `( Math.max(x1, x2), Math.min(y1, y2) )`

Bottom left: `( Math.min(x1, x2) , Math.max(y1, y2) )`

Bottom right: `( Math.max(x1, x2) , Math.max(y1, y2) )`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you intend the line to be the diagonal of the rectangle, and that line starts in `x,y` and ends in `z,w` with x < z.

Coordinates of the rectangle's vertices would be: (x,y), (x,w), (z,y), (z,w)

Answer (score 0):

The other two folks covered the diagonal, here's the center-line method.  I'm yoinking this from a shader I wrote, so forgive any type errors, I'll do my best to make them recognizable.

```
// Assume:
// Vec2 is a two-property float, with x and y
// Rect is a object that contains 4 Vec2s, representing each corner
//   in counter-clockwise order.
function Rect getRectangle(Vec2 start, Vec2 end, float width) {
    Vec2 parallel = end-start;
    parallel = normalize(parallel);

    Vec2 perpendicular = new Vec2(parallel.y,-parallel.x);
    perpendicular *= width / 2;
    return new Rect(start+perpendicular, start-perpendicular, end-perpendicular, end+perpendicular);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a line as two points and the amount of padding, this will return the four points of the bounding rectangle

```
public Point2D.Double[] padLine(Point2D lineStart, Point2D lineEnd, double padding)
{
    //have the line start at the origin so as to be represented by one point
    Point2D.Double line = new Point2D.Double(lineEnd.getX() - lineStart.getX(), lineEnd.getY() - lineStart.getY());

    //find the unit vector perpendicular to the line
    Point2D.Double perp = normalize(rotate90(line));

    //create and fill in the array of the rectangle's coordinates
    Point2D[] rect = new Point2D[4];
    rect[0] = new Point2D.Double(lineStart.getX() + perp.x * padding, lineStart.getY() + perp.y * padding);
    rect[1] = new Point2D.Double(lineStart.getX() - perp.x * padding, lineStart.getY() - perp.y * padding);
    rect[2] = new Point2D.Double(lineEnd.getX() + perp.x * padding, lineEnd.getY() + perp.y * padding);
    rect[3] = new Point2D.Double(lineEnd.getX() - perp.x * padding, lineEnd.getY() - perp.y * padding);
    return rect;
}

//same directionality, but of length 1
public Point2D.Double normalize(Point2D p)
{
    double length = Math.sqrt(p.getX() * p.getX() + p.getY() * p.getY());
    return new Point2D.Double(p.getX() / length, p.getY() / length);
}

//rotates the given point by 90 degrees
public Point2D.Double rotate90(Point2D p)
{
    return new Point2D.Double(p.getY(), -p.getX());
}
```

This just uses default java classes, `java.awt.geom.Point2D.Double` inside of `java.awt.geom.Point2D`